# Position Container below Header in ReactJS MaterialUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a navigation menu and a container in my component. The container displays behind the navigation menu and I don't manage to position it below with MaterialUI. Is it possible to position a Container and Paper element below a Header?

```
  <div className={classes.container}>
      <Head>
        property="property"
      </Head>
      <div className={classes.content}>
        {!configure && (
          <Header backClicked={backClicked}/>
        )}
        <SnackbarController />
        <Container maxWidth="md">
          <Paper elevation={2} maxWidth="md">
            <Tabs
              style={{ padding: 20 }}
              classes={{
                scroller: classes["px-3"],
              }}
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
            </Tabs>
          </Paper>
        </Container>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the component CSS file:

```
.container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 0px;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
}
.px-3 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```